# datetime conversion in EF

Tags: entity-framework

I have three tables in Sql server
User : UserId,UserName,Password,TimeZoneId(Reference to primary key of timezone)

Timezone : TimezoneId, Timezone
(values ID; 1,2,3, TimeZone : - 05:30, 12:00, -07:00)

Meeting : MeetingId,MeetingFromid,MeetingToid,MeetingStarttime,MeetingEndtime

after logging in, when i add a new meeting, if i add 4:00 in meeting start time then timezone of that user should be also added in that, same for end time as well, here is my post action method of controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Dashboard(Meeting model)
    {
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
        var timezone = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == id).Select(u => u.TimeZone.TimeZone1); //here i get timezone of logged in user (5:30 for user1)
        return View();
    }
```

now if i add MeetingStartTime as 5:00 and MeetingEndTime as 7:00 then entry in meeting table should be 10:30, 12:30, I will get date by DateTime.Now.Date but i do not know how to add both times....any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to insert meeting times as UTC to the Meeting table? [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) has a constructor with an offset parameter.

Comment: yes in other words I want to insert time as UTC

Comment: Use the DateTimeOffset with the offset from your stored time zones.

Comment: Can you please provide any link for reference..I have never heard about it before

Comment: There is a link in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should't save any offsets/timezones for your meeting. You only have to save the universal-time (UTC).
The user should choose (or the operating-system), which timezone he wants to see:

```
        // Some date..
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

        // Save this in your DB
        DateTime utcDate = myDate.ToUniversalTime();

        // When reading, convert to the local time.
        DateTime myDate2 = utcDate.ToLocalTime();

        TimeZone someOtherTimezone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
        // Show date in other timezone
        DateTime myDate3 = someOtherTimezone.ToLocalTime(utcDate);
```

If i'm planning a meeting in germany at 2:00pm. I would save 1:00pm utc in the db.
If you want to know when the meeting starts, you ask for the utc (1:00pm). If you're in germany (UTC+1) you choose timezone germany and calculate the local time: 2pm.
If you're sitting in New York, and want to participate in a telco, you would ask for the UTC-time (1:00pm) and calculate you local time: UTC-5 => 7:00am